# Show data in grid

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have an infopath form where i put a search field and by using object model inside infopath form i write code to retrieve the results. Now I want to show the results in a grid inside the infopath form. Can any one let me know wether I can use grid inside infopath or not.

Comment: Where are the results stored? What is the source that you query? Why do you use code to retrieve the results? Why not just create a secondary data source to the data.  Then drag the secondary data source onto the canvas and it will show as a repeating table. Set the data source filter fields to the value of the search field and query the secondary data source.

Comment: The list is too big around 40000 records are there. We can not retrieve through datasourve. we retrieve through code by disabling list threshold as false.

Comment: So how/where do you store the query results of the query?

Comment: Thats in SPListItemCollection item = listCountry.GetItems(objquery); I am not storing anywhere. I am using code in infopath and the result is in the item collection.

Comment: I solve this by using repeatingtable.